# Does the blacklisting of domains affect Google recaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

[1] In the past, a domain set up on a shared server was flagged as spam and blacklisted.

[2] Around the same time, a Google recaptcha timeout error began to occur every time a contact form was set up on the website for the same domain.

Until then, the form had been submitting normally, so there was no mistake in the site key or secret key settings themselves.
So, as a test, I obtained and set a new site key & secret key with Google recaptcha, and the time error stopped occurring.

Is it possible that [1] is causing [2]?
We are asking here because we have looked on the Internet and found no such precedent.
Thank you in advance.